# How do I create an array in IDL?

Tags: arrays, struct, corba, idl, idlj

```
struct Car {
  string model;
  boolean reserved;
};

interface gestion{
  Car consult(in string model);
};
```

I want to make the `consult` method return an array of `Cars`, do I need to create another struct and put a car array in it?

Answer (score 1):

You can define the array in IDL as following

```
typedef Car CarArray[5];
```

But, this is a fixed size array. If you want to create a variable size array, it is better to use a sequence like

```
typedef sequence <Car> CarSequence;
```

And than change the consult method to

```
CarArray consult(in string model);
```

or

```
CarSequence consult(in string model);
```